# Bootable USB not showing up in boot menu in UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, bootable-media

Suddenly my Dell, Windows 10 system wouldn't boot and the Dell service representative asked me to reinstall the OS. On using a bootable USB created using [Windows 10 media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10) it just wouldn't show up in the boot menu. Going into BIOS these were the options available. [image]

So, I disabled `secure boot` and enabled `legacy boot ROM` and then the USB showed up but as a legacy ROM.[image]

Upon using this legacy ROM to reinstall windows later it couldn't detect the HDD as shown below.[image]

Can anyone please help? The next thing I'm planning to do is use Rufus to create the bootable USB instead of the windows tool.

Comment: Hi there, this may be a long shot but do make sure that your formatting is set up appropriately for your bootable usb. I'm not sure how you created it but windows needs to be able to identify the correct file system in order for it to show up. This is similar to how if you have an unformatted or incorrectly formatted usb it wont show up on a standard windows install even on the desktop. The drive should be set up as something a "Windows" OS can see, If you are installing a file system on it I believe it should be either NTFS or Exfat! Hope this might help.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can gather, the bootable USB needs to be FAT32 formatted, right?

Comment: I believe that the USB should be Either NTFS or Exfat. Linux based systems typically use Fat 32 at least in my experience! I know NTFS for sure, however I would double check on Exfat!

Comment: Use Rufus and set the USB Format option as GPT Partition Scheme for UEFI Computer. With Rufus you can set the file system either as NTFS or FAT32. It will not matter. Now boot your system in UEFI Mode and check if it detects it correctly this time.